# Insert text within an Image

Tags: android, rating

How can insert a TextView within an image like the one in the photo.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TF0Lr.jpg)

Comment: That's not even a programming but a (quite simple) math/statistics problem.

Comment: You mean the sum of all ratings divided by number of ratings?

Comment: Yes @jle . Exactly that.

Comment: You have to edit your question, it is pretty unclear. In the question you only ask for a mathematical solution. That's what I commented above. If you have issues programming it you need to specify it, otherwise we don't understand it, since we're out of context

Answer (score 0):

You could try FrameLayout defined like this:

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:background="@android:color/white"
android:orientation="vertical">


    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="200dp"
        android:contentDescription="@string/some_pic_desc"
        android:src="@drawable/some_pic" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="175dp"
        android:background="@color/wallet_link_text_light"
        android:paddingLeft="10dp"
        android:paddingRight="10dp"
        android:text="TOP STORIES"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
        android:textSize="30dp" />

</FrameLayout>
```

Where resources should be defined. I have ommited the bottom menu and rounded corners since the question was not about this but you may try [read](http://www.gadgetsaint.com/tips/rounded-corners-views-layouts-android/#.W46nO7gyW00)